# Problem with Discord and Python in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-import, discord.py

I used

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

but I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using Visual Studio, and I'm not too comfortable with it, so I maybe forgot to do something.
EdiT:Fixed, i had to use the command prompt as answered.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add error message for better understanding.

Comment: First: Visual Studio has nothing to do with this, the terminal in Visual Studio is 1:1 the one of your system. Second:I just tried installing discord.py, there seems to be no syntax error. My guess is hat you've created a file `discord.py` yourself, and that gets used instead of the PyPI version. Is that a possibility? If not, please post the entire error message

Answer (score 1):

Does the error occur when starting the program, or when installing discord.py ?

for install just try:
open cmd
`pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

This is a command prompt command, with `py` referring to the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), not valid Python syntax.